# How can I get the text inside an element P excluding their possible child elements A with javascript DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to get the text (not plain-text, but formatted as well) inside each paragraph excluding their possible links. Please, explain to me in pure javascript, not jQuery.

*I wouldn't like to use neither IDs nor the method getElementById().

Example:

```js
for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('p').length; i++){
    
    p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[i];

      
   document.write(p.innerHTML);  /* Here I have the text of each paragraph but also with the links*/
   
   
}
```

```html
<p>This is a <a href="https://www.google.com">first</a> search engine.</p>
<div>Here I have also some text</div>
<p>This is a <b>web browser</b>.</p>
<p>This is another <a href="https://www.bing.com">second</a> search engine.</p>
```

The result I want should be:

"This is a search engine.This is a **web browser**.This is another search engine."

Answer (score 0):

What about this way:

1. Find all 'p' elements.
2. Loop for each element looking inside iterated element for anchors.
3. If found, remove from DOM.

```js
const textElements = document.querySelectorAll('p');

textElements.forEach(function (element) {
    element.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function (anchor) {
        anchor.remove();
    });
});
```

```html
  <p>This is a <a href="https://www.google.com">first</a> search engine.</p>
  <div>Here I have also some text</div>
  <p>This is a <b>web browser</b>.</p>
  <p>This is another <a href="https://www.bing.com">second</a> search engine.</p>
```

Snippet with for loops and document.getElementsByTag

```js
const textElements = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('p').length; i++) {
    // get next p tag
    var someParagraphElement = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[i];
    
    // length of tag inside paragraph
    var lenghtOfA = someParagraphElement.getElementsByTagName('a').length;
    if(lenghtOfA){
        for (var j = 0; j < lenghtOfA; j++) {

            // a tag inside p 
            var aTag = someParagraphElement.getElementsByTagName('a')[j];
            aTag.remove();
        }

    }
}
```

```html
<p>This is a <a href="https://www.google.com">first</a> search engine.</p>
      <div>Here I have also some text</div>
      <p>This is a <b>web browser</b>.</p>
      <p>This is another <a href="https://www.bing.com">second</a> search engine.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you very very much zapala.grzegorz!! From the two answers I get, this is the simple one. Howerever I want to ask you: 1. Is it pure javascript or jQuery? Because the code is a bit strange for me. 2. Can you write the piece of code inside the loop? For example:  for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('p').length; i++){... or is it for (i = 0; i < document.document.querySelectorAll('p').length; i++){...

Answer (score 0):

You can just make an off-DOM copy of the elements, remove the anchor elements from those, then ask for `textContent`:

```js
let container = document.createElement('div');

[...document.getElementsByTagName('p')].forEach(p => container.innerHTML += p.innerHTML);

// remove links
[...container.querySelectorAll('*')].forEach(el => {
  if (el.tagName === 'A') el.remove();
})

console.log(container.innerHTML);

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = container.innerHTML;
```

```html
<p>This is a <a href="https://www.google.com">first</a> search engine.</p>
<div>Here I have also some text</div>
<p>This is a <b>web browser</b>.</p>
<p>This is another <a href="https://www.bing.com">second</a> search engine.</p>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Here's basically the same solution in ECMAScript 5, which you might be more used to:

```js
// create a container element not in the DOM to copy stuff to
var container = document.createElement('div');

// get all paragraph elements
var paras = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

// iterate over each paragraph and add its innerHTML to the container
for (var i = 0; i < paras.length; i++) {
  container.innerHTML += paras[i].innerHTML
}

// get all container child elements
var containerChildren = container.querySelectorAll('*');

// iterate over them and remove any links
for (var j = 0; j < containerChildren.length; j++) {
  if (containerChildren[j].tagName === 'A') containerChildren[j].remove();
}

console.log(container.innerHTML);

// make the result visible
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = container.innerHTML;
```

```html
<p>This is a <a href="https://www.google.com">first</a> search engine.</p>
<div>Here I have also some text</div>
<p>This is a <b>web browser</b>.</p>
<p>This is another <a href="https://www.bing.com">second</a> search engine.</p>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, connexo, but I don't understand this type/style of javascript. This is not the classical javascript I have been learning.

Comment: @PabloDavidMartín Okay, I'm just gonna add the very same solution using ES5.

Comment: Thank you @connexo. This code is now much clearer for me. The only things I don't understand are this (+=) assigning a variable (4th line of code) and this comparison (===) (7th line), but I have to keep on learning..